# SQL Database backup using SMO and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, smo

I am trying to run this seemingly simple piece of code which is repeated several times all over the net, but I am getting errors in the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common

Private Sub BackupDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackupDatabaseToolStripMenuItem.Click
'Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server.
Dim srv As Server
srv = New Server
'Reference the AdventureWorks2008R2 database.
Dim db As Database
db = srv.Databases("AdventureWorks2008R2")
'Store the current recovery model in a variable.
Dim recoverymod As Integer
recoverymod = db.DatabaseOptions.RecoveryModel
'Define a Backup object variable. 
Dim bk As New Backup
'Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up.
bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database
bk.BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of AdventureWorks2008R2"
bk.BackupSetName = "AdventureWorks2008R2 Backup"
bk.Database = "AdventureWorks2008R2"
'Declare a BackupDeviceItem by supplying the backup device file name in the constructor, and the type of device is a file.
Dim bdi As BackupDeviceItem
bdi = New BackupDeviceItem("Test_Full_Backup1", DeviceType.File)
'Add the device to the Backup object.
bk.Devices.Add(bdi)
'Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup.
bk.Incremental = False
'Set the expiration date.
Dim backupdate As New Date
backupdate = New Date(2006, 10, 5)
bk.ExpirationDate = backupdate
'Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.
bk.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate
'Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server.
bk.SqlBackup(srv)
End Sub
```

I am getting errors on these lines:
Dim bk As New Backup

*Error  5   Type 'Backup' is not defined.*

bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database

*Error  6   'BackupActionType' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

Dim bdi As BackupDeviceItem

*Error  7   Type 'BackupDeviceItem' is not defined.*

along with other similar errors

Am I missing some "imports"?
I got the code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.sqlbackup.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add reference to the following assemblies (not just import)

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I had not referenced "Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended" because it was not included in the list provided by Microsoft in their documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162166(v=sql.90).aspx

Or it was there but didn't see it.